# Meaning of 足を引きずる

Tags: meaning

Jisho says that 足を引きずる means 'to limp'. My good paper dictionary seems to suggest that it means 'to drag one's feet' due to tiredness, for example. What range of meanings does 足を引きずる actually encompass:

1. to limp e.g. due to an injury?
2. to drag one's feet due to tiredness?
3. to drag one's feet due to a reluctance to do something e.g. "he dragged his feet about going to the dentist"?
4. anything else?

Comment: ３番は「[足取]{あしど}りが[重]{おも}い」「重い足取りで歯医者に」とかどうでしょう？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, 足を引きずる is always physically dragging one's feet. So it could be 1 or 2 or any other reason that causes the person to drag their feet in the literal sense.

For 3, a similar expression that means starting something with reluctance in a figurative way is [重い腰を上げる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%87%8D%E3%81%84%E8%85%B0%E3%82%92%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B/#jn-306194).